# Performance for multiple partitioned subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, join, query-performance

I have a database with one main table and multiple history/log tables that stores the evolution over time of properties of some rows of main table. These properties are not stored on the main table itself, but must be queried from the relevant history/log table. All these tables are big (on the order of gigabytes).

I want to dump the whole main table and join the last entry of all the history/log tables.

Currently I do it via subqueries as follows:

```sql
WITH
  foo AS (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY date DESC) AS rownumber,
      ...
    FROM table1),
  bar AS (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY date DESC) AS rownumber,
      ...
    FROM table2)
SELECT
  ...
FROM maintable mt
JOIN foo foo ON foo.itemid = mt.itemid AND foo.rownumber = 1
JOIN bar bar ON foo.itemid = mt.itemid AND bar.rownumber = 1
WHERE ...
```

The problem is that this is very slow. Is there a faster solution to this problem?

I am only allowed to perform read-only queries on this database: I can not make any changes to it.

Comment: You could run the explain plan for this query, that should show you where the highest cost is: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/how-to-read-an-execution-plan

Comment: Second on the request to show your explain plan / DBMS_XPLAN output.  Also, on average, how many history rows are there per distinct `item_id`?  What are the relative sizes of the tables (e.g., is history 2x bigger than the main table?  10x?  100x?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In actual Oracle versions it's usually better to use laterals/CROSS APPLY, because CBO (oracle cost-based optimizer) can transform them (DCL - `lateral view decorrelation` transformation) and use optimal join method depending on your circumstances/conditions (table statistics, cardinality, etc).

So it would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  ...
FROM maintable mt
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT *
      FROM table1
      WHERE table1.itemid = mt.itemid
      ORDER BY date DESC
      fetch first 1 row only
      )
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT *
      FROM table2
      WHERE table2.itemid = mt.itemid
      ORDER BY date DESC
      fetch first 1 row only
      )
WHERE ...
```

PS. You haven't specified your oracle version, so my answer is for Oracle 12+